# SUM(Time(0)) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any links that could help me or point me into the correct direction please??

I am having difficulties getting my table to work correctly.

I have a clock system that I am trying to build a report on in Visual Studio.

I have succeeded in building the report viewer application but in SQL I have the following problem.

I have a table called `ClockTimes`:

```
DeviceID    Clock Event   CLockIN           CLockOUT            TimeWorked  SeqNo       DriverId        Company Fleet_Code  FirstName   LastName    Employee_no ID_Tag
58041       IN            25/08/2014 08:02  25/08/2014 17:23    09:20:56    1730183296  000016A63DF6    CompA   FleetA      Andrias     NA          5001        DF6
58041       IN            14/08/2014 12:06  14/08/2014 12:06    00:00:19    1720446507  0000157CBEF7    CompA   FleetA      Daniel      NA          5002        EF7
12676       IN            14/07/2014 12:04  14/07/2014 12:04    00:00:10    1695160943  PULSIT005       CompB   CompB       Pieter      NA          1004        C2C
58041       IN            25/08/2014 08:01  25/08/2014 17:23    09:21:49    1730182991  000015F463D3    CompA   FleetA      Quenten     NA          5003        3D3
58041       IN            25/08/2014 08:02  25/08/2014 17:23    09:20:51    1730183710  000016A6C320    CompA   FleetA      Drikus      NA          5004        320
58041       IN            27/08/2014 08:10  NULL                NULL        1732093463  000016A6A9CA    CompA   FleetA      Martin      NA          5005        9CA
12676       IN            14/07/2014 15:24  14/07/2014 15:25    00:00:37    1695329075  PULSIT006       CompB   CompB       Bonita      NA          1008        969
12676       IN            17/07/2014 09:16  17/07/2014 13:46    04:29:30    1697530293  PULSIT010       CompB   CompB       Monique     NA          1005        878
58041       IN            22/08/2014 14:56  25/08/2014 17:23    02:26:55    1728100080  000015F463D3    CompA   FleetA      Quenten     NA          5003        3D3
58041       IN            25/08/2014 08:02  25/08/2014 17:23    09:20:48    1730183606  000016A6A9CA    CompA   FleetA      Martin      NA          5005        9CA
```

With this I am trying to build a report where I get the person who clocked with a selected time period with start and end date and the get the total time worked in format HH:mm:ss

Example shown here:

```
Employee_no Company Fleet_Code  FirstName   LastName    CLockIN             CLockOUT            Total_Time_Worked
1004        CompB   CompB       Pieter      NA          14/07/2014 12:04    14/07/2014 12:04    00:00:10
1005        CompB   CompB       Monique     NA          17/07/2014 09:16    17/07/2014 13:46    04:29:30
1008        CompB   CompB       Bonita      NA          14/07/2014 15:24    14/07/2014 15:25    00:00:37
5001        CompA   FleetA      Andrias     NA          25/08/2014 08:02    25/08/2014 17:23    09:20:56
5002        CompA   FleetA      Daniel      NA          14/08/2014 12:06    14/08/2014 12:06    00:00:19
5003        CompA   FleetA      Quenten     NA          25/08/2014 08:01    25/08/2014 17:23    11:48:44
5004        CompA   FleetA      Drikus      NA          25/08/2014 08:02    25/08/2014 17:23    09:20:51
5005        CompA   FleetA      Martin      NA          25/08/2014 08:02    25/08/2014 17:23    09:20:48
```

Thus if a person clocked more than once it must be grouped to a single entry on the grid but with the Time accumulated over all the working hours in between the start and end date.

Comment: I am working with SQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating some example data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
( '08/24/2014 08:02:21', '08/25/2014 17:23:15');
```

This query will split the time into Day/Hour/Min/Sec

```
SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) AS Days,
    (DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate) % 24) Hours,
    (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, EndDate) % 60) Minutes,
    (DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartDate, EndDate) % 60) Seconds
FROM @MyTable
```

Here is the output:

```
StartDate                EndDate                 Days Hours  Minutes  Seconds
2014-08-24 08:02:21.000  2014-08-25 17:23:15.000 1    9      21       54
```

Comment: Thank you That is what i needed, i did use this query but did not understand it i used it as DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) AS Days ,DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate) AS Hours, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, EndDate) AS Minutes, DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartDate, EndDate) AS Seconds.

Comment: The % is a mod function, I use it to just get the extra hours of the last day, the extra mins of the last hour, and the extra seconds of the last minute.